# aeb-pro / example sign

Tags: pdf, miktex, security

I using MikTeX 2.9. Right now I'm looking at Digitally signing the generated pdf. I ran accross the AcroTeX Education Bundle and am attempting to compile the example `sign.tex` from the `aeb-pro` examples. I get an error that I don't understand:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\expVerb ->\sigInfo 
                   {
l.15 \sigInfo{
```

surely `\sigInfo` is a package command - or is this something I'm supposed to define? Is there a package dependency I've possibly missed? I must be misreading the documentation because I don't see anything specific to this command.

I get this error when compiling with pdflatex and also when compiling (a slightly modified version) with Latex.

Should I be using a different TeX?